# Disconnecting from a wifi network in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, debian

I am trying to figure out how to disconnect from wifi network without actually taking down the entire interface like in the command below.

```
ifconfig wifi0 down
```

Is there any way to disconnect from wifi in vanilla bash without having to use any external package ?

Comment: I can't say **no** definitively, but I'll be real surprised if what you ask for is possible. The main purpose of a shell is to make it easy to control external programs. The unix/linux philosophy is that a program should perform one task well (and if appropriate be able to communicate thru (to and from) via `|` pipes). Will be interested to see if someone has a way of doing this without calling some external program. Also, can you point to something in the GUI interface that distinguishes between "disconnecting" vs "taking down the entire interface" (I don't seen the diff). Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

It depends completely on what program is managing your wifi connection.

The default for debian, NetworkManager, has a cli tool, called nmcli.

You can list all configured connections with:

```
nmcli con list
```

Then you can deactivate a connection with:

```
nmcli con down <id>
```

Comment: "Vanilla bash" does not have builtins to connect to a wifi network.

Comment: This is nice, because it does not require root privilege (just like the GUI method does not)

Answer (score 0):

To remove all connections do:

```
nmcli --fields UUID,TIMESTAMP-REAL con show | grep never |  awk '{print $1}' | while read line; do nmcli con delete uuid  $line;    done
```